# No me deja agregar los datos a la base de datos, me dice no such column: "y lo que pongo"

Tags: java, sqlite

Tengo un problema con mi código, en el cual trato de ingresar datos a una base de datos, pero me regresa siempre "no such column", de lo que veo si se conecta a la base de datos, pero no me deja insertar los datos en la tabla.
La base de datos que estoy utilizando es sqlite.

El código de la clase donde se inserta es este:

```
public boolean insertar(String sql){
    boolean valor = true;
    conectar();
    try {
        consulta.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            valor = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    finally{
        try{    
             consulta.close();  
             conexion.close();  
         }catch (Exception e){                 
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }  
    }
    return valor;
}

public ResultSet consultar(String sql){
    conectar();
    ResultSet resultado = null;
    try {
        resultado = consulta.executeQuery(sql);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Mensaje:"+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Estado:"+e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Codigo del error:"+e.getErrorCode());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+e.getMessage());
        }
    return resultado;
}

public void guardar(Articulo articulo){
    insertar("INSERT INTO Articulo (Nombre,Descripcion,Marca,Cantidad,Fecha) values ("+articulo.getNombre()
                +",'"+articulo.getDescripcion()
                +"','"+articulo.getMarca()
                +"','"+articulo.getCantidad()
                +"','"+articulo.getFecha()+"')");
}
```

Comment: Hola. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade la descripción de la tabla en la que quieres insertar los datos **como texto**.

Comment: Agrega el script con el que creas tu tabla o su descripción como indica Alfabravo, saludos.